# Request for quota n2_cpus not approved

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The request N2_CPUS for new quota limit 36 CPU not approved. I only choose my region.
Anyone has experience about this?
Why? And how to make this approved.

I do have submitted 2 times and not approved.

Should I request for committed N2 cpus or n2 CPUs?

Thanks in advance…………..

Comment: Did you have reached the current quota? What's your previous usage on that project?